# Passing csrf token through $.ajax() data not working

Tags: jquery, ajax, django

So I'm trying to make ajax commenting in my django app, and I've encountered the:

```
Forbidden (CSRF token missing or incorrect.): /app/437/
```

error. After reading through many SO answers it seems the most used and simple method to deal with this error is by passing through the csrf token through $.ajax() data like this:

```
$('.comment_form').on('submit', function(e) {
e.preventDefault();

var url = window.location.href.split('?')[0];
    console.log(url)

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: url,
    data: {
        text: $('.comment_text').val(),
        'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{csrf_token}}',
        },
    success: function() {
        $('.comment_div').append("<div class='comment_div'><h3>username</h3><p>" + text + "</p></div>");
        console.log(text);
    }
})
});
```

Here's my template if you're curious:

```
{% block comments %}
{% load widget_tweaks %}

<div class="commentsContainer">

    <form action="" class="comment_form">{{csrf_token}}
        {{ comment.comment_text|add_class:"comment_text" }} <!-- this is a textarea-->
        <input type="submit" value="Comment" class="comment_submit">
    </form>
    <div class="comment_div">
        <h3>username1</h3>
        <p>Some text</p>
    </div>
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

Here's my view:

```
def article(request, category, id):

    name = resolve(request.path).kwargs['category']
    for a, b in CATEGORY_CHOICES:
        if b == name:
            name = a
            instance = get_object_or_404(Post, id=id, category=name)

    allauth_login = LoginForm(request.POST or None)
    allauth_signup = SignupForm(request.POST or None)
    comment = CommentForm(request.POST or None)

    context = {
        'comment': comment,
        'instance': instance,
        'allauth_login': allauth_login,
        'allauth_signup': allauth_signup
    }


    return render(request, 'article.html', context)
```

Comment: You haven't shown your view, so we can't tell whether the problem might be there. [The docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/csrf/#ajax) describe how you can set a header on all ajax requests, so that you don't have to manually add the token to the post data as you are trying to do. For non-ajax requests, you should have `{% csrf_token %}` in the `<form>` tag, not `{{ csrf_token }}`.

Comment: Added the views. And isn't this an ajax request? That's why I changed it from `{% csrf_token %}` to `{{ csrf_token }}`

Comment: If you change `{{ csrf_token }}` to `{% csrf_token %}` then the hidden input in your `<form>` tag, then the hidden input will be correctly rendered. This would work for non-ajax requests (e.g. if JavaScript is disabled).

Comment: The view looks ok. Is your javascript in a template? How is it rendered? Using the `X-CSRFToken` approach is probably easier than debugging your JavaScript.

Comment: My javascript is in my `base.html`, which is the parent template of my comments html in my question. And I just tried to add the `headers: {
  'X-CSRFToken': "{{ csrf_token }}"
}` to my $.ajax() and nothing changed.

Comment: `'csrfmiddlewaretoken'` doesn't need to be in quotes. Instead, do this: `csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}'`

Comment: You haven't shown the rendered javascript from your base template yet. You don't have to add `headers: { 'X-CSRFToken': "{{ csrf_token }}"`, if you add the `getcookie` and `$.ajaxSetup` code from the docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `{% csrf_token %}` inside your `<form>`; it will  render a hidden input, which has a name and a value. Then, in the ajax's data, you should send that input's *value*, like this:

```
...
data: {
    text: $('.comment_text').val(),
    csrfmiddlewaretoken: $("input[name='csrfmiddlewaretoken']").val(),
},
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe your headers need to look like this:

```
headers: {
  'X-CSRFToken': "{{ csrf_token }}"
}
```

Also, in your form, you should use `{% csrf_token %}` rather than `{{ csrf_token }}`

Check out the docs for info about this. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/csrf/#ajax

Comment: I looked at the docs and tried adding that getCookie() function to my .js file. But what goes in the template and where does it go in the template?

Comment: You need to add the `getCookie()` function and `var csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');` line to your script tag, as well as the `csrfSafeMethod` function and `$.ajaxSetup({...})` from the next code block in the docs. Then you can remove the `'csrfmiddlewaretoken': '{{csrf_token}}',` line from your `data`.

Comment: On the actual `script` tag? So how would it look here? `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'js/base.js' %}"></script>`

Comment: When I said the script tag, I mean put it in the same place as your current `$.ajax({...})` request.